# Change field from activity history

Tags: activities

I can change the field that is displayed as a title in the activity history? Currently is the subject:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a provision to change it but you can update it with what you want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As manjit mentioned, you cannot change the existing value. However you can try below workaround.

1. Use workflow rule to update subject value from 'No subject' to any
   value defined in workflow field update.
2. Select any default value from lov's on Subject field.
3. Else you can manually update.

[image]

Was able to achieve using WF.

Thanks